# How can I implement multithreading in this for loop?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, minimax

Consider this code snippet

```py
from tqdm import trange


def main_game(depth1, depth2):
    # some operator with complexity O(20^max(depth1,depth2))
    return depth1+depth2


DEPTH_MAX = 5
total = 0
for depth1 in range(1, DEPTH_MAX + 1):
    for depth2 in range(1, DEPTH_MAX + 1):
        for i in trange(100):
            total += main_game(depth1, depth2)

print(total)
```

I'm using minimax algorithm in main_game() with branching factor = 10

Now, since the third for-loop has a time-consuming function (up to 100*O(20^5) in time complexity), is there any way I can make it run faster? I'm thinking of parallelizing (multithreading for example). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `multiprocessing`, and from there `Pool().starmap()`. `starmap()` feeds your function with the prepared tuples of arguments in a parallelized manner. And collects the result synchronously.
If the order of the result doesn't matter, you could use the asynchronous version `.starmap_async().get()`.

There are also `Pool().apply()` and `Pool.map()` with their `_async()` versions, but you actually need just to learn `Pool().starmap()`. It is only some Syntax difference.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
n_cpu = mp.cpu_count()

# let's say your function is a diadic function (takes two arguments)
def main_game(depth1, depth2):
    return depth1 + depth2

DEPTH_MAX = 5
depths = list(range(1, DEPTH_MAX + 1))

# let's pre-prepare the arguments - because that goes fast!
depth1_depth2_pairs = [(d1, d2) for d1 in depths for d2 in depths]

# 1: Init multiprocessing.Pool()
pool = mp.Pool(n_cpu)
# 2: pool.starmap()
results = pool.starmap(main_game, depth_1_depth_2_pairs)
# 3: pool.close()
pool.close()

total = sum(results) # this does your `total +=`

## in this case, you could even use
results = pool.starmap_async(main_game, depth_1_depth_2_pairs).get()
## because the order doesn't matter, if you sum them all up
## which is commutative.
```

This all you can write slightly more nicer using the `with` construct (it does the closing automatically, even if an error occurs, so it does not just save you typing but is more secure.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

n_cpu = mp.cpu_count()

def main_game(depth1, depth2):
    return depth1 + depth2

DEPTH_MAX = 5
depths = range(1, DEPTH_MAX + 1)
depth1_depth2_pairs = [(d1, d2) for d1 in depths for d2 in depths]

with mp.Pool(n_cpu) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap_async(main_game, depth_1_depth_2_pairs).get()

total = sum(results)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I'm looking for.